# Is locking a dereferenced mutex bad behaviour?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, mutex

c++ pseudocode class:

Simple class which has a member variable, and mutex to control access to it.

I'm curious about the pro's and con's of managing the data and it's access.
In a multithreaded enviroment, is it wrong to use the approach to accessing and locking the member mutex in cbMethodA()?

I've seen samples where the members are accessed directly, and it seems incorrect to do that. The class exposes access via a public method for a reason.
Also, dereferencing a mutex to then lock it doesn't seem like best practice. Any comments?
Thanks

```
 class A
   {
    public:
        A():val(0);
        ~A();
        int getVal(void);
        static void cbMethodA();
        static void cbMethodB();

     private:
        Mutex m_mutex;
        int val;
    }

    int A::getVal(){
    {
       int returnVal = 0;
       lockMutex(m_mutex);
       returnVal = m_val;
       unlock(mutex);
       return returnVal;
    }

 void A::cbMethodA(void *ptr)
{
    A* ptr = static_cast<A*> (ptr);
    //get val
    lockMutex(ptr->m_mutex);
    //read val
    int tempVal = ptr->m_val;
    unlockMutex(ptr->m_mutex);
    //do something with data
}

 void A::cbMethodB(void *ptr)
{
    A* ptr = static_cast<A*> (ptr);
    //get val
    int tempVal = ptr->getVal();
    //process val....
}
```

Comment: Which mutex implementation were you planning to use?  The answer to this question would let us give a more definitive answer.  A mutex is used to protect a critical section of code, which might involve accessing a shared resource or some shared variables.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm not implementing anything, just reading some code online, and was curious when I saw the direct members accessed, as I've always written code to use get/set. I wasn't sure if I was missing some quirk due to the static method or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a direct application of SPOT (**S**ingle **P**oint **O**f **T**ruth), a.k.a. DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself), two names for a [single important idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  You've created a function for accessing `val` that performs some tasks that should always go along with accessing it.  Unless there is some private, implementation-specific reason to access the member field directly, you should probably use the getter method you define.  That way, if you change the synchronization mechanism that protects `val`, you only need to update one piece of code.

I can't think of any reason why "dereferencing a mutex to lock it" would be a *bad* thing, repeating yourself *is* a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks brenns. It was code in a project I was reading about online. I wasn't sure if I wasn't understanding something about the static member (or something else), so I thougth I'd ask here :) (This comment is a fine example of WET I think) ;)

Comment: ... **W**rite **E**verything **T**wice?

Comment: Yes, my explanation to both you and Tim was the same. Bad joke I guess :)

Comment: If that oxymoron makes any sense.